# Error occurred in mounting file system during Linux bootup with busybox

Tags: linux, busybox

I am working on an embedded Linux system, which uses busybox as init.
When system bootup, there are two error logs shown as follows,

```
[    3.901185] Run /linuxrc as init process
[    3.909861] process '/bin/busybox' started with executable stack
mount: mounting devpts on /dev/pts failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting tmpfs on /dev/shm failed: No such file or directory
```

After I login to the Linux and ran 'mount' command, I got followings,

```
# mount
......
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=41768k,nr_inodes=10442,mode=755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000)  <<<<
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)   <<<<
```

To my surprise, they are already mounted there!!
The /etc/fstab used by busybox is as follows,

```
# cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount pt>      <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/root       /               ext2    rw,noauto       0       1
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  defaults,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=0666   0       0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   mode=0777       0       0
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   mode=1777       0       0
tmpfs           /run            tmpfs   mode=0755,nosuid,nodev  0       0
sysfs           /sys            sysfs   defaults        0       0
```

I think there might be some delay for /dev/pts and /dev/shm to be present to the system, so I added delay in mount.c of busybox, but got the same *error*!

I also tried edit /etc/fstab by moving those 2 lines to the end of the file, but got the same *error*!

Then I changed the kernel commandline to 'init=/bin/bash' to goto bash when bootup.
And in bash, I checked /dev/pts and /dev/shm, they are not there!

I tried to mount them manually, but still hit the error of 'No such file or directory'.

I don't know why this happened, it seemed harmless, but it is annoying to see 'Error message' in system, so I want to figure it out and fix it.

Comment: What if you do not [try to attempt to] mount these two mount points? They must be mounted automatically as far as I understand.

Comment: I commented out them from /etc/fstab, and reboot the system. With mount, they are still there!! Seemed automatically mounted by someone. Who did this?

Comment: Mountin' trolls, who else?

Comment: I don't know who mounted them and how they were mounted..... :-(. I think the SDK provider  might also hit this issue, that is why he created /dev/shm and /dev/pts in the rootfs building in the host.

Comment: I think I found where are they mounted, it is in /etc/init.d/rcS, which firstly mkdir /dev/pts then mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts, the same to /dev/shm. So it is true that when busybox starts up, there is NO /dev/pts or /dev/shm, and mounting FS per /etc/fstab should report the error.

Answer (score 1):

With the testing suggested by Artem, I found out the root cause of the error and how to fix it.

When busybox is started as init process in the system, it first checks `/etc/fstab` and tries to mount file systems according to the file. And that is true there is NO `/dev/shm` or `/dev/pts` at that time to do the mounting by Busybox, so Busybox complains about this.

Then in `/etc/init.d/rcS`, it will also mount some file systems including `/dev/shm` and `/dev/pts`. And `rcS` will firstly `mkdir /dev/pts` and `/dev/shm` before mounting the file systems. That is why there is NO error reported and that is why they are mounted even being commented out in `/etc/fstab`.

So now I will keep using `rcS` to do their mounts and comment them out in `/etc/fstab`.